# C# Entity Framework Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I'm working on a Web Cash Register in C# (MVC 5 ASP.net EF6), Code First technology, and I'm trying to make a database with migrations. In my database context file I select the tables I want to add in the database, but when I build the migration, it just uses all the excisting Models I have made for the database, instead of the ones I've selected in the DB Context file. Why does this happen? Why Immediately everything, and not just the ones I selected? Here's my code:

```
using WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace WebCashRegister.DAL
{
    public class WebCashRegisterContext : DbContext
    {
        public WebCashRegisterContext() : base("WebCashRegister")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Price> Price { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Product> Product { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.DeliveryLine> DeliveryLine { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Delivery> Delivery { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the migration, generated with Entity Framework. It just uses all the models I have instead of the ones in the DBContext shown above.

```
namespace WebCashRegister.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class eerste : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Category",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FoodNonfoodCategory = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Product",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        Price_ID = c.Int(),
                        Category_ID = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Price", t => t.Price_ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Category", t => t.Category_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Price_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Category_ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Price",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        ProductPrice = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Sale = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Delivery",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        DateTimeSent = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        DateTimeEstimatedDelivery = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        DateTimeDelivered = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        Status_ID = c.Int(),
                        Store_ID = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Status", t => t.Status_ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Store", t => t.Store_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Status_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Store_ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.DeliveryLine",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Delivery_ID = c.Int(),
                        Product_ID = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Delivery", t => t.Delivery_ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Product", t => t.Product_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Delivery_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Product_ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Status",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Delivered = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Store",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        StreetName = c.String(),
                        AdressNumber = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        ZIP = c.String(),
                        State = c.String(),
                        Country = c.String(),
                        Retailer_ID = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Retailer", t => t.Retailer_ID)
                .Index(t => t.Retailer_ID);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Retailer",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        StreetName = c.String(),
                        AdressNumber = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        ZIP = c.String(),
                        State = c.String(),
                        Country = c.String(),
                        CEOName = c.String(),
                        Stores = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Store", "Retailer_ID", "dbo.Retailer");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Delivery", "Store_ID", "dbo.Store");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Delivery", "Status_ID", "dbo.Status");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DeliveryLine", "Product_ID", "dbo.Product");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DeliveryLine", "Delivery_ID", "dbo.Delivery");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Product", "Category_ID", "dbo.Category");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Product", "Price_ID", "dbo.Price");
            DropIndex("dbo.Store", new[] { "Retailer_ID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.DeliveryLine", new[] { "Product_ID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.DeliveryLine", new[] { "Delivery_ID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Delivery", new[] { "Store_ID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Delivery", new[] { "Status_ID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Product", new[] { "Category_ID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Product", new[] { "Price_ID" });
            DropTable("dbo.Retailer");
            DropTable("dbo.Store");
            DropTable("dbo.Status");
            DropTable("dbo.DeliveryLine");
            DropTable("dbo.Delivery");
            DropTable("dbo.Price");
            DropTable("dbo.Product");
            DropTable("dbo.Category");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help! Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Delivery` class has navigation properties to `Store` and `Status` so Entity Framework pulls those classes into the Model too, then the `Store` class has a `Retailer` navigation property. These tables are all required to support the model that you have defined in code so Entity Framework is generating the correct migration code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! It makes a lot of sense now. I was very confused first since I didn't include the tables in the context but now it makes sense. Do I still need to add them in the context though just because it's maybe more clear to read?

Comment: @Helix That's up to you really. If you only intend to access the data via navigation properties then I see no reason to add them to the context for the sake of neatness. But aren't you going to need `DbSet`s so that you can easily do CRUD on `Store`s and `Status`es and `Retailer`s?